# Flutter packages implementation

Tags: flutter

how can we know the functionality of any flutter packages without implementing them in our flutter project? This seems really tricky to implement because we mostly don't know how this package work and why this package meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you implementing a package from pub.dev, you can search source code of a package (right section with info about package, issue tracker link etc.). Additionally, you can visit on issue tracker of a package, when can see errors, feature requests (for know available functionality or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [flutter packages page](https://pub.dev) and search package. When you open packages page in right side you can see link to Github. You can open and see package code in Github.